# Can Stripe process a network token?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment-processing, android-pay

Android Pay recommends requesting gateway tokens if the merchant uses Stripe:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/payments/android-pay

But can Stripe process if merchant passes a network token instead of a gateway token?

Answer (score 0):

Stripe can only use a Stripe Token, which means you'll either need to use the [Android SDK](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/pay-with-google) or Elements' [Payment Request Button](https://stripe.com/docs/elements/payment-request-button) to make this work.

Comment: But in the case of Apple Pay, Stripe seems to be to able to decrypt the network token info and return a Stripe token. https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/custom#apple-pay